# Angular universal not rendering once deployed, ok in local

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm a bit mystified as to what's wrong with my app. After building it I can run it locally and the server side rendering works, but once it has been deployed to the server ssr stops working.

Normally you see some sort of error on the express app if there's issue, but  I'm not getting one.

The only thing I can determine is only content from my api that's not rendering. Just doesn't make any sense why it works locally and not on the server.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I need to look at as I'm stumped.

Comment: please share your configuration, code and steps followed for angular universal implementation.

Comment: Doesn't matter looks like it an issue that a few people are having.
https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/856

Answer (score 0):

Add the API URL inside your host file to resolve.

edit /etc/hosts to the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 api.example.com
```

Note that API domain should also be in this VM box.